# Connecting PHP source code and submit form to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to learn PHP and I'm trying to connect a MySQL database with my PHP code to make a submit form that lets me input data into the database. My problem is that the source code is connecting but the HTML isn't posting the variables to the PHP file. I could really use some help.

This is my HTML source code

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Form Input Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Form Input Employees Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <table>
    <form action="input.php" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address" size="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
      name="submit" value="Sent"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And this is my PHP source code

```
<?php

$user_name = "fees0_14446440";
$password = "********";
$database = "fees0_14446440_addressbook";
$server = "sql107.0fees.net";

mysql_connect("$server","$user_name","$password");

mysql_select_db("$database");


$order = "INSERT INTO Trial

        (name, address)

        VALUES

        ('$name',

        '$address')";


$result = mysql_query($order);

if($result){

    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");

} else{

    echo("<br>Input data is fail");

}
?>
```

Comment: This should be mandatory for any question with [php] and [mysql] tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: You're not using any POST variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the POST data in PHP's `$_POST` variable. It should hold all the values that were passed via the POST method.

`$name = $_POST["name"];`

Comment: You are welcome. The SO question that vhu posted in a comment to your original question is definitely a good read as well.

Comment: @user3717206 fyi you still need to sanitize your data!

Answer (score 2):

put POST values into variable

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
```

before sql query
and write sql query as

$order = "INSERT INTO Trial

```
    (name, address)

    VALUES

    ('".$name."',

    '".$address."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php

$user_name = "fees0_14446440";
$password = "********";
$database = "fees0_14446440_addressbook";
$server = "sql107.0fees.net";

mysql_connect("$server","$user_name","$password");

mysql_select_db("$database");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$order = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Trial (name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')");

if ($order) {
    echo '<br>Input data is successful';
} else {
    echo '<br>Input data is not valid';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Form Input Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Form Input Employees Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address" size="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
      name="submit" value="Sent"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In PHP code

```
$order = "INSERT INTO Trial

        (name, address)

        VALUES

        ('$_POST["name"]',

        '$_POST["address"]')";
```